# Add / Convert my physical DVD collection to M4V or iTunes Library?

Tags: itunes, dvd, media, home-server, video-conversion

I have a whole bunch of DVD's, and want to put them into a personal media server / file server (could be any OS - Mac, PC, or Linux). I want to be able to "map" this media repository with my iTunes and make it available to my computers (with iTunes or Quicktime), iPads, iPhones, Apple TV's (2010 models), etc. You get the idea.

I also want the best possible quality - for example I currently have a physical DVD player that both upconverts to 1080p and cleans up DVD's so they look pretty good on any display.

This must all be legal and of course is for personal use only.

What's the best way to do what I'm trying to do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the excellent software [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/), it has a very intuitive interface and has presets for popular devices including mp4 for Apple iDevices including iPhone, Apple TV, iPad, iPod Touch, iPod Video, etc.

I've found this software to be the easiest way to convert video.

Comment: Good suggestion. I would like to see some alternative suggestions as well. What about "UP" conversion - video cleaning, enhancement etc. into at least 720p format? My iPhone 4 will do 720 :)